# can anybody explain me this proof in detail?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

i was reading Brouwer's fixed-point theorem in wikipidia,,,here im not understanding this line as shown below,.

The following example shows that BFPT(Brouwer fixed point theorem)  doesn't work for domains with holes. Consider the following function, defined in polar coordinates:

f(r,θ) = ( r,θ +π/4)

which is a continuous function from the unit circle to itself.

can anybody explain me this proof  in detail  ?

Comment: If you look at that map on the unit circle, then it rotates it by $1/8$ of a turn, so fixes no point on the circle.

Comment: how it rotate by 1/8 ,,im not getting @ lord shark the unknown

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh Do you understand what polar coordinates are? This map changes the angle by $\pi/4 = 2\pi/8$, one eighth of a turn.

Comment: thanks @user296602 but how it  doesn't work for domains with holes. ..pliz explain me

Comment: Because the **circle** provides a counterexample. This is different from the theorem on the **disk**.

Comment: that mean circle has hole  and disc has not hole,,,,,,,,but  when  i see the DvD -vcd disc there is a  small hole in centre  @user296602

Comment: @Jameslegolegoh A DVD is not what we mean mathematically when we talk about a disk. A disk is a set like $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le 1\}$. It has no holes.

Comment: thanks a lot @ user296602,,,im getting now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rotation on $D^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, or the map $f(x) = -x $ on that same domain. Both have no fixpoints; on $D^2 = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$ these maps do have a unique fixed point namely $(0,0)$. The map you describe from wikipedia is on the circle (which is compact, which my domain is not), and is just a rotation. Every angle $\theta$ becomes $\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}$ (radians), and as a full circle $(360^\circ$) corresponds to $2\pi$ (in radians), this is an angle of $\frac{1}{8}$ of $360$, i.e. $45^\circ$. This same map, as said, also works on $D^2$ minus the origin.

Comment: thanks u so much @ henno Brandsma  for clearing my doubts